# Which technology should be used: ActiveX, Applet, Browser Extension, other?

Tags: browser, applet, activex, digital-signature

In my scenario I have users who need to sign documents from an IIS served web application (ASP.NET MVC in my case).

I can assume my users all have the same type of SmartCard and the same type of certificate with the same proper middleware drivers (CSR) installed on their Windows PCs.

What is the actual architecture that I can use in this scenario to ask them to enter their certificate's PIN from the web page (but out of the sandbox I think) and use their private certificate to sign documents?

In the past I've used signed applets or signed ActiveX to interact with user's hardware and make appear, for example, the PIN request diaolg window invoked on the client's driver. Are these technologies actually viable or there is a more modern approach to this kind of issues?

Comment: I have the same question too! I have seen that the WebCryptoAPI does not support this. I have found this: https://github.com/open-eid/chrome-token-signing/  that still requires an external executable (as far as I can tell...). So, I am totally lost here... I cannot believe that ActiveX and Java are still the best choices! Perhaps my grandfather was using the exact same technologies! :D